# NodeJS how does the escape()/escapeId() method of MySQL module works?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to understand the escape method of the NodeJS module (to build my version of that module), does it only remove the metacharacters/special characters or does it something different?

Comment: If you're talking about [mysql](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) package it uses [sqlstring](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlstring) package for `escape` and `escapeId` method. You could use it as well to build your module instead of implementing it yourself

Comment: https://github.com/mysqljs/sqlstring/blob/master/lib/SqlString.js

Comment: Yes, but it is also a personal research, i want to know what is behind that. I searched the SqlString module inside the node_modules and found nothing so, i decided to ask here.

Comment: Why do you want to create an own version of for such a critical component instead of using a well tested one?

Comment: @t.niese the question is also a personal research, i wanted to know how it works not only to build my version of that module.

Comment: Personal research is ok, but you really shouldn't use that in production code. There is so much you can do wrong when it comes to escaping.

Comment: @t.niese i am not going to use that code in production, i am a student trying to understand this, also thanks to everybody for the support!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mysql](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) pacakge uses [sqlstring](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlstring) package for `escape` and `escapeId` methods.

You could check [source code](https://github.com/mysqljs/sqlstring/blob/master/lib/SqlString.js) to see how it works.

`escape`:

- Numbers are left untouched
- Booleans are converted to `true` / `false`
- Date objects are converted to `'YYYY-mm-dd HH:ii:ss'` strings
- Buffers are converted to hex strings, e.g. `X'0fa5'`
- Strings are safely escaped
- Arrays are turned into list, e.g. `['a', 'b']` turns into `'a', 'b'`
- Nested arrays are turned into grouped lists (for bulk inserts), e.g. `[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]` turns into `('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')`
- Objects that have a `toSqlString` method will have `.toSqlString()` called and the returned value is used as the raw SQL.
- Objects are turned into `key = 'val'` pairs for each enumerable property on the object. If the property's value is a function, it is skipped; if the property's value is an object, toString() is called on it and the returned value is used.
- `undefined / null` are converted to `NULL`
- `NaN / Infinity` are left as-is. MySQL does not support these, and trying to insert them as values will trigger MySQL errors until they implement support.

`escapeId`:

- Arrays are turned into list, e.g. `['a', 'b']` turns into `'a', 'b'`
- Strings are safely escaped

Safely escape string:

```
{
  '\0'   : '\\0',
  '\b'   : '\\b',
  '\t'   : '\\t',
  '\n'   : '\\n',
  '\r'   : '\\r',
  '\x1a' : '\\Z',
  '"'    : '\\"',
  '\''   : '\\\'',
  '\\'   : '\\\\'
};
```

Comment: So it just reads the incoming data and rewrites it in a MySQL acceptable format am i right? Is this the best way to prevent SQL Injections?

Comment: Yes, and also escapes all `SQL`-significant syntax like closing quotes (`'`, `"`), comments (`--`, `*/`) etc.

Comment: @Stecco prepared statements can be (depending on how they are implemented) safer because the combination step of query and values is then done by the SQL server and not the 3rd party library. (Under the assumption that the SQL server is up to date and well maintained)

Comment: @t.niese is right.

Comment: @t.niese Ok, so how is it possible to make prepared statements in NodeJS?

Comment: But as OP says it's only for learning purposes

Comment: @Stecco Prepared statments is sill on the TODO of  [mysqljs/mysql](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#todo) module.